# It seems queue restart not work on windows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am learning queues chapter. I open a terminal to start queue in:`php artisan queue:work --daemon`. I found i cannot type in terminal so I open another terminal and type:`php artisan queue:restart`. It seemed the first terminal didn't stop. But it didn't execute jobs in database after. So is there something wrong with my step? Thanks.

Comment: any clue on `laravel.log` (in storage dir)

Comment: What queue driver are you using?